# JavaScript why cannot select the elements

Tags: javascript

I'm sure I've make a mistake but I can't figure it out...

Why I cannot select the elements with class name `test` by `querySelectorAll?

I'm getting an error: cannot read properties of undefined, but the elements are definitely defined because when I type `content` in the console, it shows the nodeList...

```js
const content = document.querySelectorAll('.test');

content.classList.add('hide-content');
```

```css
.Content {
  width: 180px;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: green;
}

.hide-content {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<div class="Content"></div>
<div class="Content test"></div>
<div class="Content test"></div>
```

Comment: `The Document method querySelectorAll() returns a static (not live) NodeList representing a list of the document's elements that match the specified group of selectors.` Use the document.querySelectorAll('.test')[0] or  document.querySelector('.test')

Comment: _“but the elements are definitely defined”_ — That’s not what the error message is about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to mdn:

> The Document method querySelectorAll() returns a static (not live)
> NodeList representing a list of the document's elements that match the
> specified group of selectors.

It is like the `document.getElementsByClassName` which return you a nodelist and you have to specify the index or you could use `document.querySelector`

```js
const content = document.querySelectorAll('.test');

content[0].classList.add('hide-content');
```

```css
.Content {
  width: 180px;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: green;
}

.hide-content {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<div class="Content"></div>
<div class="Content test"></div>
<div class="Content test"></div>
```

If there are several of them, use an array like `forEach` or `for` loop instead

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting the elements, the problem is that `content` is not a single element, but a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList). In order to manipulate each element, you'll need to iterate over it with `.forEach` and apply the change to each element.

```js
const content = document.querySelectorAll('.test');

content.forEach((el) => {
  el.classList.add('hide-content');
})
```

```css
.Content {
  width: 180px;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: green;
}

.hide-content {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<div class="Content"></div>
<div class="Content test"></div>
<div class="Content test"></div>
```

**More notes on reading errors**:

The error message is very useful so be sure to read it carefully in the future. The error says:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add')

Notice it says "reading 'add'". This means the error isn't saying that your query result is undefined, but that `classList` is undefined. Understanding this difference may lead you to investigate what `content` actually is and get you closer to solving your problem.

Comment: It's not an array. It's an "array-like" collection of elements. You can't, for example, use `map` on it until you convert it to an actual array.